# Laravel authentication failed after using Crypt::encrypt method

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, encryption

I am using `Laravel 5.4`.

Recently, I have had a requirement to **encrypt** the data of `users table`. So that, I have followed [this][1] link, and created an `Encryptable trait` as,

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;
use Config;
use Crypt;

trait Encryptable
{
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable) && Config::get('app.encrypt_data_at_rest')) {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable) && Config::get('app.encrypt_data_at_rest')) {
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }
        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

and used it in my `User model` like;

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
class User extends BaseModel implements AuthenticatableContract, 
                                         AuthorizableContract,
                                         CanResetPasswordContract  {

    use SoftDeletes;
    use Encryptable;

    protected $encryptable = ['username'];
```

And inserted a record and the `username` encrypted successfully.

But now, the issue is, I am **not able to login** using this `username` and `password`.

In the database, the `username` seems encrypted. If I get that specific user's `username` in my controller, (e.g. `User::find(89)->username`) then it returns me the **decrypted** username (i.e. simple string that I have inserted while creating this user) due to `getAttribute()` method of `Encryptable trait`.

But however I am not able to use `Auth::attempt()` method as it returns `false`. I am passing the **non-encrypted** `username` and `password` while using `Auth::attempt()` method.

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Fix: do not encrypt the username. It makes absolutely zero sense in any of available universes.

Comment: Due to General Data Protection Regulation, the client is forcing me to do it.

Comment: I removed my answer since it was incorrect. I would use a second column to store a one-way hashing value such as sha256 that can be used when searching for a username match. Check to see if GDPR really requires you to obfuscate a username, sometimes encrypting the whole database on a global level is enough. Or not showing the username to the outside world is good too

Comment: Encrypting the username does NOTHING related to GDPR. If you hashed it, then that would do something. Encrypting the username still lets you decrypt it, therefore you can read it and do whatever with it. It appears that neither you or your client understand what you're doing (no offense meant, you're a big boy). Fix is still: **do not encrypt the username**. Hash it.

Comment: @N.B. what about the email field? If it is getting used for authentication? Does it required to be encrypted or not??

Comment: No, encryption doesn't hide the data. You can still decrypt it, you own the service, so you can get the plain text info back. Why do you or your client think that encryption does anything? Who are you hiding the data from? Yourself? You can always decrypt the data, it's not hidden. What do you achieve with encryption, save the fact you can't authenticate anyone. When you encrypt the **same** plaintext, you get **different** ciphertext. That's why you can't encrypt  the username and match it. Hashing is a one way process, that's what you're after.